# Datos NAN en captura de variables desde formulario en js

Tags: javascript, json

Estoy haciendo un formulario con js  que toma datos de dos variables para devolver otra capturandolos por medio de inputs , cuando reviso el tipo de dato que captura sale NAN , como puedo solucionar esto ?

Necesito que entre un dato de tipo numerico a un objeto json para devolver un calculo con if

```
function mostrar_talla(){
  document.getElementById("Enviar-buton").addEventListener("click",resultado,false);
}


function resultado(){
  var obtener_datos=[
    {
      altura:(document.getElementById("ALTURA").Value),
      peso  :(document.getElementById("PESO").Value)
    }
  ]

 if (typeof(obtener_datos.altura)!=NaN||typeof (obtener_datos.peso)!=NaN) {
  var multiplicacion=parseInt(obtener_datos.altura)*parseInt  (obtener_datos.peso);  
  console.log(document.getElementById("TALLA").innerHTML=multiplicacion);
 } else { console.log("es un dato NAN");

 }
}
```

El archivo html es un form , sin conexión a ningun php o similar.

```
//ARCHIVO HTML //
       <form  name ="registro"action="#" method="get" id="registro">



        <div id="ALTURA">
                <label for="ALTURA"><strong>ALTURA:</strong></label>
                    <input type="text" id="ALTURA" nombre="ALTURA"
                    class="ALTURA" placeholder="Altura en CM" required> </div>    
         </br>  
         <div id="PESO">          
        <label for="PESO"><strong>PESO:</strong></label>
            <input type="text" id="PESO" nombre="PESO" id="PESO"
            placeholder="Peso en Kg" required> 
        </div>  
        </br>


        <div id="TALLA">
            <label for="TALLA"><strong>TALLA:</strong></label>
                <input type="text" id="TALLA" nombre="TALLA"
                class="TALLA" placeholder="TALLA DE kimono"> </div>
        </br>        



        </br>
        <div id="Enviar-buton">
            <label for ="Enviar"></label>
            <input type="submit" id="Enviar-buton" onclick="mostrar_talla()"  class="Enviar-buton"></div>

            <div id="Limpiar-buton">
            <label for ="Limpiar"></label>
            <input type="reset" id="Limpiar-buton" class="Limpiar-buton"></div>

         </form>
```

Gracias por su ayuda :)

Comment: hacer un typeof NaN no te va a devolver NaN te va a devolver 'number', así que porfa intenta corregir tu condición puesto que siempre se va a cumplir (debido a que 'number' es diferente de NaN), lo segundo es que a lo mejor ya lo sabes, pero NaN se forma cuando se realiza una operación incompatible entre dos tipos de valores, por ejemplo si intentas algo tan loco como dividir el string 'A' entre 10 ('A' / 10) = NaN, sin embargo hay operaciones que si son posibles con las cadenas de texto, por ejemplo la concatenación ('A' + 'B' = 'AB').

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varios errores.

**Primer error:** caer en la trampa de que `typeof` te devuelve la clase o un objeto comparable a alguno que quieras comparar, por ejemplo mira esta condición:

```
typeof(obtener_datos.altura)!=NaN||typeof (obtener_datos.peso)!=NaN
```

Vamos a proyectar esta condición en un snippet con valores que conozcamos, y veremos que ocurre:

```js
if(typeof(NaN)!=NaN||typeof ("10")!=NaN){
  console.log("Alguno o ambos son iguales a NaN!");
}else{
  console.log("Ninguno es igual a NaN!");
}
```

Como vemos he puesto `NaN` en uno de los `typeof` y la condición siempre se cumple, así que proseguimos al segundo error:

**Segundo error (error de lógica):** tu condición siempre se va a cumplir así como esta por dos razones, la primera es que `typeof` siempre nos trae una cadena de texto representando el tipo de dato:

```js
console.log(typeof NaN);
```

El segundo problema es que estas usando `||` en vez de `&&` en tu condición, en tu caso esto es malo puesto que tienes la idea de usar estos valores en una operación matemática en el futuro, pero recuerda que `||` ocurre solo si alguna de las condiciones se cumple y no necesariamente todas.

mientras que `&&` solo ocurre si todas se cumplen, lo cuál en este caso sería lo ideal (Que pasa si uno de tus valores es `NaN` y lo intentas multiplicar luego?, el resultado es otro `NaN`).

**Tercer error:** No puedes usar el operador `==` o `===` para comparar `NaNs` puesto que `NaN` siempre es diferente a `NaN` (para evitar largas historias acerca de `NaN` y el porque esto pasa, omitiré la explicación de esto y su por qué).

Pero podemos verlo aquí:

```js
const sonIguales = NaN == NaN || NaN === NaN;

console.log(sonIguales);
```

Como vemos nos arroja `false`, es decir, ni el operador de igualdad (`==`) ni el operador estricto de igualdad (`===`) nos sirven para comparar nans, por lo tanto ni intentes usar el operador igual o estrictamente igual para comparar `NaNs` porque simplemente van a fallar estrepitosamente.

Y entonces como comparamos `NaNs`??, una forma posible es usando `Number.isNaN`:

```js
console.log(Number.isNaN(NaN));
```

**Cuarto error:** porque intentas acceder a la propiedad de un array como si fuesen las propiedades de un objeto??

Checa esta parte:

```js
var obtener_datos=[
  {
    altura: "Lo que habias puesto...",
    peso  : "Lo que habias puesto 2..."
  }
]

//No existen así por lo que no tiene sentido accederlos:
console.log(obtener_datos.altura);
console.log(obtener_datos.peso);

           //obtener_datos.altura no existe!, existe es obtener_datos[0].altura;
           //obtener_datos.peso   no existe!, existe es obtener_datos[0].peso;
if (typeof(obtener_datos.altura)!=NaN || typeof (obtener_datos.peso)!=NaN) {
}
```

**Quinto error:** **La propiedad Value en los elementos HTML no existe**, existe es la propiedad **value**, ojo distingase, **todo en minusculas**.

y tu claramente tienes aquí:

```
  altura:(document.getElementById("ALTURA").Value),
  peso  :(document.getElementById("PESO").Value)
```

La palabra values en mayusculas.

Bien con estas correcciones creo que ya serias capaz de modificar tu código y hacer que funcione, espero sea de utilidad esta información.

Comment: Hola , gracias por sus aclaraciones , estoy recién comenzando en java script , para resolver este problema he intentado simplemente obteniendo los datos del formulario de este modo hice este codigo function mostrar_talla(){
  document.getElementById("Enviar-buton").addEventListener("click",resultado,false);
}


function resultado(){
  var obtener_datos= {
      altura:(document.getElementById("ALTURA").value),
      peso  :(document.getElementById("PESO").value)
    }
    
  }  aun sigo teniendo datos NAN , tienes un ejemplo de como  tomar datos desde un formulario en js? gracias.

Comment: Edita te pregunta a como tienes el código actualmente y veremos como te podemos ayudar vale??